# Chinese Remainder Theorem Modified

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have a set of n congruences of form
$$ X \equiv a1 \pmod p$$
$$ X \equiv a2 \pmod q$$
$$ X \equiv a3 \pmod r$$

where p, q, r are relatively prime. Let
$$P =  \Pi \hspace{5pt}p^aq^br^c$$

How can we calculate
$$ X \mod P$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lift the original congruence into the form
$$X \equiv a_1'\pmod {p^a}$$
where $a_1'$ belongs to the set of all residue classes such that $a_1' \equiv a_1 \pmod p$.

Do something similar for $q$ and $r$. Then applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem to $p^a,\ q^b$ and $r^c$ will give you the set of necessary results.

Note that there will be many solutions. In general we will have $p^{a-1}$ lifted congruence classes for the first congruence, $q^{b-1}$ for the second congruence and $r^{c-1}$ for the third. Each triplet will correspond to a unique solution giving a total of $p^{a-1}q^{b-1}r^{c-1}$ solutions modulo $P$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
Let's say we are given X % 3  = r(say) and I need to find X % 27. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it would be the set of congruence classes $$\left\{r,\ r+3,\ r+6,\ \cdots,\ r+24\right\}$$

Comment: With X given is it possible to find which congruence class X % 27 will belong?

Comment: Like I said, the solution is not unique. Suppose $X \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ then we cannot uniquely specify $X \pmod{27}$. All we can say is that $X$ will belong to one of the congruence classes $$X\in\left\{2,\ 5,\ 8,\ \cdots,\ 23,\ 26\right\}$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be $p^{a-1}q^{b-1}r^{c-1}$ lifted congruences? For example, if we know $x\bmod{2}$ there are $2^{4-1}=8$ possible values of $y\bmod{2^4}$ so that $x\equiv y\pmod{2}$, not $2^{4-2}(2-1)+1=5$.

Comment: @robjohn You are of course right. I don't know what possessed me when I counted the congruences. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think we can if $a,b,c\ge 2$.

Suppose $X\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.
Can we find $X\pmod{16}$?

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you know, and $a>1$, $b>1$ or $c>1$, then you can't.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Suppose you are given X % p is there a way to calculate X % p^a?
For e.g. suppose we are given X % 3 and I need to find X % 27. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Not uniquely: if x%3=0, then x%27 could be any of 0,3,6,...,24.